# Keras Sequential model is giving improper prediction when we put longer text

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
CONFIG.input_layers = 2
CONFIG.output_layers = 2
CONFIG.amount_of_dropout = 0.2
CONFIG.batch_size = 100
CONFIG.epochs = 500

def create_model(output_len, chars=None):
    print('Build model...')
    chars = chars or CHARS
    model = Sequential()

    for layer_number in range(CONFIG.input_layers):
        model.add(recurrent.LSTM(CONFIG.hidden_size, input_shape=(None, len(chars)), kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization,
                                 return_sequences=layer_number + 1 < CONFIG.input_layers))
        model.add(Dropout(CONFIG.amount_of_dropout))
    model.add(RepeatVector(output_len))

    for _ in range(CONFIG.output_layers):
        model.add(recurrent.LSTM(CONFIG.hidden_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization))
        model.add(Dropout(CONFIG.amount_of_dropout))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(chars), kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def iterate_training(model, X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, ctable):
    for iteration in range(1, CONFIG.number_of_iterations):
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=CONFIG.batch_size, epochs=CONFIG.epochs,
                  validation_data=(X_val, y_val), shuffle=True, verbose=2)
```

I'm training with countries:

```
United States of America
United Arab Emirates
India
China
Australia
Canada
Germany
Poland
Brazil
Afghanistan
```

I'm facing issues with india china mostly. I have created noisy data for each country using script.

e.g these are few records, I'm training with more.

```
unitei arab emirates,united arab emirates 
dnited arab emirates,united arab emirates 
united amrab emirates,united arab emirates 
indea,india 
igndia,india 
chinab,china 
chpina,china 
chrna,china 
cmina,china 
lchina,china
```

> Script to create the noisy data:

```
def create_noisy_data(word):
    letters    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
    deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R]
    transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]
    replaces   = [L + c + R[1:]           for L, R in splits if R for c in letters]
    inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in letters]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)
```

The above function creates the noisy data for each country and as per the country name length the create_noisy_data function creates noisy data.

> It works fine when I train only for:

```
India
China
Australia
Canada
Germany
Poland
Brazil
Afghanistan
```

or

```
United States of America
United Arab Emirates
Afghanistan
```

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: You face issues during training or prediction? The title and content is a bit confusing. If it is related to predictions, can you share a sample of actual vs expected?

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:ml] tag. It has nothing to do with "machine learning".

Comment: I'm using Bi-directional LSTM now, thanks for commenting.